# Expectancy value of sale of fishballs

Tags: statistics

I am doing some elementary statistics and the following problem stumpled me a bit.

> A merchant receives two batches of fish cakes from two different factories, but
>    with the same produces. Thus one can not determine witch batch came from which 
>    factory. The batches are labeled $A$ and $B$, and they have the following contents
>   \begin{align*}
> \textbf{Batch A:} & 100 \text{ boxes, whereof } 10 \text{ with mushy cakes, labeled } F_1 \\
> \textbf{Batch B:} & 100 \text{ boxes, whereof }  5 \text{ with mushy cakes, labeled } F_1; \\ & \text{and in addition } 10 \text{ with foul smell and taste, labeled } F_2 \text{ , whereof } \\ & 1 \text{ with both } F_2 \text{ and } F_2 \,.
> \end{align*}
>   Consider the errors mushy cakes and foul smell and taste to be impossible
>   to detect from the outside, and can only be detected by destroying the inspected box.
>
> **b)** Given that the merchant picked two boxes without error 
>   and one with only $F_1$ error, what is the probability that the boxes came from $A$?

I deduced that 
$$
\overbrace{3 \left( \frac{90}{100}\right)\left( \frac{10}{99}\right) \left( \frac{89}{98}\right)}^{\large P(E\,\cup\,F\,\cup\,E\,\mid\,A)} = \frac{267}{1078}\,,\quad
\overbrace{3 \left( \frac{85}{100}\right)\left( \frac{4}{99}\right) \left( \frac{84}{98}\right)}^{\large P(E\,\cup\,F\,\cup\,E\,\mid\,B)} = \frac{34}{385}
$$
This is not the same as in the solution manual, (is this still correct?)
Thus the probability that the cake came from *Batch A* is
$$
P(A\,\mid\,E\,\cup\,F\,\cup\,E) = \frac{267/1078}{34/385 + 267/1078} = \frac{1335}{1811} \approx 73.7 \% $$
Is this correct? This is needed for part **c)** which I am unsure about =)

> The merchant leaves the batches in his warehouse and forget which batch is which. 
>      He then pulls 3 cakes from one of the batches and observes he obtained two   error-free cakes and one mushy cake ($F_1$).
>
> The merchant then wishes to sell the fish cakes for $1\$$, but is worried
>   about the foul cakes. All the boxes will be sold, and he decides on the following.
>
> - Mushy cakes, only error $F_1$, the money is refunded.
> - Error $F_2$ or $F_2+F_1$ the money is refunded + $15\$$ in compensation.
>
> **c)** The merchant wants to maximize his income, and has now four options>
>
> - Sell all the remaining boxes.
> - Sell the rest of the boxes in the unit of the three observed boxes came from.
> - sell all the boxes of the other unit.
> - Not sell any of the boxes at all.
>
> what is the expected income in each case? 
>     Which option should the merchant choose?

**My question is does the probability of which batch he did pick, affect the expectancy value?**

I deduced the following for the three cases

1. $E(x) = (90 + 85 - 2) \cdot 10 - 10 \cdot 15 = 23$
2. ??? $E(x) = \cfrac{1335}{1811} \cdot \Bigl[ (88) \cdot 1 - 0 \cdot 9 \Bigr] + 
                    \cfrac{476}{1811} \cdot \Bigl[ (83) \cdot 1 - 0 \cdot 3 - 9 \cdot 15 \Bigr]  \approx 51.203$
3. ???
4. 0

I am really clueless as to how to calculate the expectency value of $2$ and $3$. 
Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Batch $B$ contains $86$ good boxes, $4$ that are $F_1$ only, $9$ that are $F_2$ only, and one that is $F_1$ and $F_2$. The question is badly worded and could also be interpreted as saying that there are $85$ good boxes, $5$ that are $F_1$ only, $9$ that are $F_2$ only, and one that is $F_1$ and $F_2$; that appears to be the interpretation that you used.

In Batch $A$ there are $10\binom{90}2=40,050$ samples of $3$ boxes, two of which are good and one of which is $F_1$; in Batch $B$ there are $4\binom{86}2=14,620$ such samples. The probability that such a sample is from Batch $A$ is therefore $\frac{40050}{40050+14620}=\frac{40050}{54670}\approx0.0.73258$. Had I done the calculation by your method, which is also correct, I’d have had

$$\frac{\frac{3\cdot90\cdot89\cdot10}{100\cdot99\cdot98}}{\frac{3\cdot90\cdot89\cdot10}{100\cdot99\cdot98}+\frac{3\cdot86\cdot85\cdot4}{100\cdot99\cdot98}}=\frac{90\cdot89\cdot10}{90\cdot89\cdot10+86\cdot85\cdot4}=\frac{80100}{109340}=\frac{40050}{54670}\;,$$ clearly the same as the answer that I got by the other approach.

On my interpretation of the wording he still has $174$ good boxes, $13$ $F_1$ boxes, and $10$ boxes that are $F_2$ and possibly also $F_1$, so if he sells them all, he makes $$197-23-10\cdot15=24\;.$$ On your interpretation he has one good box fewer and one more $F_1$ box, so he makes only $23$. (I could also, and more simply, have calculated it as $174-10\cdot15=24$.)

Suppose that he sells the rest of the boxes in the tested batch. If that is Batch $A$, he’s selling $88$ good boxes and $9$ $F_1$ boxes, making an income of $88$. If it’s Batch $B$, on my interpretation he’s selling $84$ good boxes, $3$ $F_1$ boxes, and $10$ boxes that are $F_2$ and possibly also $F_1$, so his income is $84-10\cdot15=-66$. His expected income is the weighted sum of these two possibilities, the weights being their respective probabilities of occurrence. The probability that this is Batch $A$ is known from the earlier part of the question, and the expected income is $$\frac{4005}{5467}(88)+\frac{1462}{5467}(-66)=\frac{255,948}{5467}\approx46.82\;.$$

You can use the same approach to calculate the expected income if he sells the boxes in the untested batch.

Comment: Okay, so I had the right idea for both parts just that I was slightly off with the numbers. (Silly to miscount the number of boxes). So if he sells the untested batch the probability would be $$\frac{4005}{5467}(-66)+\frac{1462}{5467}(88)$$? I was unsure if one had to *weigh* the expectancy value, thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: The incomes won’t be $88$ and $-66$, because he’ll be selling the whole batch. If the untested batch is Batch $A$, his income will be $90$; if it’s Batch $B$, it will be $86-15\cdot10=64$. You want $$\frac{4005}{5467}(-64)+\frac{1462}{5467}(90)\;.$$ Yes, the expectation is always the sum of the possible values, each weighted by its probability. You’re welcome!

Comment: I might post this as a follow up question. But our teacher asked us the following: Assume the merchant start selling from the Batch he took the samples from. As soon as a customer complains about a fish cake with $F_2$ fallacy, he switches batches. If he sells 4 cakes, then one with a fault. He will no longer sell any cakes. What is now the expectancy value?
I really just want to know how to deal with the fact that I do not know when a $F_2$ deficiency shows up. Do i sum up all the probabilities? =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: That looks as if it could get a bit ugly; you should probably post it as a separate question.